# Docker not running on http://0.0.0.0:8161

Tags: activemq-classic

I ran

```
docker run -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 rmohr/activemq
and the output shows
```

Docker docs are viewable at:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8161
```

However when I go to this address I get an error

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

Tried: http://127.0.0.1:8161/

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Justine this is related to the apache mq project only. I don't think it's required to delete this.

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost:8161/ or http://127.0.0.1:8161/ worked for me.
With docker-machine, you can get the IP of the VM from the command
docker-machine ip output.